# NSDate problem with retrieving events from calendar

Tags: iphone

I am receiving two values from NSDatePicker (startDate, endDate).  After that I try to retrieve Calendar Events  between these two dates.  Instead of startDate, endDate I give distantPast, distantFuture.

The program not showing any error.  When using this code I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  What's wrong with this code?

```
NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] autorelease];
unsigned int unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit; 
NSDateComponents *difference=[[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
difference = [[sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:startDate 
                             toDate:endDate options:0] autorelease]; 
double days = [difference day]; 
NSLog(@"DAYSS   %@",days);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noted three mistakes here :

1. Don't autorelease the `currentCalendar` you get, no need to
2. `days` should be a `NSInteger` not a `double`, since `[difference day]` will return a `NSInteger`.
3. Trying to log `days` using `%@` won't work, it used to print object description, use `%i`.

In my opinion the app crashes on `NSLog(@"DAYSS   %@",days);`, replacing it using `%i` will put the crash away, but you should corrects the others mistakes too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as Vince already explained the mistakes u have done ,

also [NScalender currentcalender] has a memory leak - u can't autorelease it

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/173758-nscalendar-currentcalendar-leak.html

you should check this out - contains all features of event kit

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160